# How to populate a dropdown button with JSON external file in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to json, and struggling with a section of code. I want to populate a bootstrap `dropdown` button with data from a json file( country names).

This is my html code:

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group" id="countryBut">
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Your Country <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="but-dropdown dropdown-menu">

    </ul>
</div><!--end of btn-group-->
```

This is my json external file - countries.json

```
{
  "countries": [{
    "name":"Afghanistan"
  }, {
    "name": "Albania"
  }, {
    "name": "Argentina"
  }, {
    "name": "United Kingdom"
  }]
}
```

And this is my javascript file inside html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('countries.json', function(data) {
    for( var index in data.countries ) {
        $('#countryBut ul').append('<li><a href="#" data-maker="'+data.countries[index].name
   +'>'+data.countries[index].name+'</a></li>');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Trying to get it to work, but can't find any helpful resources. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript part is somehow strange.

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('countries.json', function(data) {
        for( index in data.countries ) {
            $('#countryBut ul').append('<li><a href="#" data-maker="'+data.countries[index].name+'">'+data.countries[index].name+'</a></li>');
        }
    });
});
```

This is how your JSON should look:

```
{
    "countries": [
        {
            "name":"Afghanistan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania"
        },
        {
            "name": "Argentina"
        },
        {
            "name": "United Kingdom"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks @JohnAnkanna

Comment: i've tried it, but still not displaying anything on dropdown. But thanks for your effort

Comment: A best solution then for you is to use developer tools from for example, Google chrome. Console will show you if you have any problems. This part here should work, but maybe you fail somewhere else we don't see.

Comment: Have i targeted the json file correctly? It's stored in the root folder with index.html

Comment: Gives me the following error: jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Titan/countries.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Hmm,look at your json structure. Remove first `[` and last `]` in file since right now you don't have valid JSON format.

Comment: Run file from xampp with http://localhost/Titan/index.html rather with file: protocol.

Comment: i think there might be a problem with my json file? syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Hey your front end `html` file you forgot to add the class `dropdown` to div so just add the class as you are using the `bootstrap` for `UI`

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown" id="countryBut">
```

Try Like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('countries.json', function(data) {
            for( var index in data.countries ) {
        $('#countryBut ul').append('<li><a href="#" data-maker="'+data.countries[index].name+'">'+data.countries[index].name+'</a></li>');     }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, i think there might be a problem with my json file structure.

Comment: @shaun don't forget to use `var` in the `for loop` when you use the variable first time .........

Comment: @shaun did you confirm that data is loading use `console.log(data)` once

Comment: yes, it is loading, no more errros, but displaying an empty dropdown list.

Comment: @shaun it is because you forgot to put the closing `>` for anchor tag and you only assigning to `data-maker` not for the `a ` tag now i edited the code just check that

Comment: is there another way, maybe i should use the <select> method

Comment: yea you need create the dom  for` <select>` and `<option>`

Comment: @shaun did u try the code it is perfectly solved your issue i think

Comment: i did, i literally copied your code over, but still don't display anything, no errors though

Comment: @shaun if that is the case then you write your code in js fiddle and send me the link

Comment: hi, sorry i only saw the comment now...will do it now, still having the same issue with it

Comment: @shaun you forgot to add the class `dropdown` to `div` in the `html` file just check the code i edited

Comment: got it, changed it to your code,just gives me an empty dropdown

Comment: @shaun can you edit the question with latest code you are trying after these many trials .....so we will get the clarity definitely very minor mistake is happening ....nothing more than that ...

Answer (score 0):

the json file looks like this now:

```
"countries": [{
  "name": "Afghanistan"
}, {
  "name": "Albania"
}, {
  "name": "Argentina"
}, {
  "name": "United Kingdom"
}]
```

Hope it's right now.

Comment: No. Check my first answer how it should looks.

Comment: it still says my countries.js file isn't formed correctly

Comment: yours also says that

Answer (score 0):

[Dropdown-when clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQdCP.png)

That's what it does when I click on it, doesn't display anything, json file seems to load fine[Json file-network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yCwH.png)